# Download file from https url with authentication using wildcards

Tags: curl, https, download, wildcard, nexus

I need to download an artifact from nexus repository using command line. The artifact file name is unknowm but the extension name is always `*.zip`. I am using the curl command with wildcard characters. When I execute the command it says `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

`curl --insecure  -O -u username:password -v https://nexus.internal.org.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/org/artifact/1.4.0/*.zip`

```
> Accept: */*
>
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   0< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 22:28:35 GMT
< Server: Nexus/2.14.2-01
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
```

The file is actually present in the URL location. Is the command I'm running alright?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good way to do this with the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543468/download-file-from-https-url-with-authentication-using-wildcards)
that basically requests the content of an entire prefix, sets some boundaries into the recursion and filters accepted files by a shell-like pattern.

If I am not mistaken, the command to do what you want would be:

```
wget --recursive --level=1 --no-parent --no-directories \
  --accept '*.zip' \
  --directory-prefix=. \
   https://nexus.internal.org.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/org/artifact/1.4.0/
```